# how to check number of files store in one drive for business details for all users

Tags: onedrive-for-business

Can someone help me on this -  how to check number of files store in one drive for business details for all users

Thanks in Advance
Kavitha

Answer (score 0):

First you must obtain all users of your tenant, after that you need to iterate through them and using the following resource you can get the list of items for each user:

```
/drive/root/children
```

After that, to obtain the metadata of each item, you can use the following resource:

```
/drive/items/{item-id}
```

Full documentation:
https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm#item-resource

I hope you find it useful